# How to check via web if .NET Framework4 Client is installed 

Tags: .net-4.0

Is it possible to check via web site if end use has installed .NET Framework4 Client ? 
It's desirable if this way doesn't use any plugins (flash or silverlight).

Comment: Why do you need to check if the client has .NET 4 in order to run a non Flash/Silverlight website? All the code is run on the server, the client just has to render the HTML which is independent of .NET.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question - however it would help your question if you explained what you want to do, what you've tried and what's not working.

Comment: I just have a task to check it.

Comment: You can't get this sort of access to a client machine without running some code locally. If you explained **why** you want to do this someone might be able to help you.

Comment: I've already said that it's just my task TO CHECK IT. And nothing more.

Comment: Well - if you want to direct the user to a different installer depending on whether they've got the right version of .NET installed (for example) then you can build that logic into your installer which does run on the client. The installer doesn't have to include the .NET runtime - it just needs to know it needs to go off and download and install the right version for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the server side, the best you can do is sniff the [user agent](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.43) that is sent with the request to the website.  In it you'll usually see something along the lines of:

```
.NET <version number>
```

Or something to that effect.

Of course, there are major drawbacks to this (as there is with any user agent detection) which warrant *not* doing this:

- The user agent can be spoofed
- Parsing strings that are not structured is generally error-prone
- Not all browsers (i.e. non-IE browsers) are obligated to send this information

That said, [ChrisF's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484862/how-to-check-via-web-if-net-framework4-client-is-installed#comment12005296_9484862) asking why is somewhat relevant, in the sense that you are better off having code execute on the client side to detect this, as there are [more definitive ways (checking the registry) of determining if .NET 4.0 is installed on the client](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2010/05/04/detection-keys-for-net-framework-4-0-and-visual-studio-2010.aspx), using mechanisms that you just don't have available to you from the server side.

The thing is, if the code is served up from the server side, then it will probably be sandboxed in *some* way, and you'll have to figure out a way to access the registry (which is typically restricted in most sandboxes for code downloaded from the web).